# Angular momentum & Energy using Yukawa's potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, angular-momentum, potential

I was doing my Gravitation problems and I found this one that I'm unable to solve.

> Yukawa's theory for nuclear forces states that the potential energy
>    corresponding to the attraction force produced by a proton and a neutron is:
>     $$U(r) = \frac{k}{r}e^{-\alpha r},\ k<0,\ \alpha > 0$$
>     From the expression of it's effective potential, find the module of it's angular momentum and it's energy, for which it's possible a circular movement with a radius $r_0​$.

I've tried several things, none of them leading to something meaningful. In fact, I know that expression for effective potential is:
$$U_{ef}(r)=U(r)+\frac{L}{2r^2}$$

So I imagine I would need to find $L$ fist in order to get the expression for $U_ef$, but I'm not able to remember nor find any kind of formula linking $U$ and $L$. Would you please help me out?

PS: Once I know how to find $L$ I know how to end it, since:
$$\frac{dU_{ef}}{dr} = 0 \Leftrightarrow r = r_0$$
is the expression of the energy of a circular movement with a radius $r_0$

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework problem, I won't provide a full solution, but here's a nudge in the right direction.  Take a look at these two plots of the effective potential:

[k = -1, $\alpha$ = 1, L = 0.25](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph%20of%20-Exp%5B-r%5D%2Fr%20%2B%200.25%2F%282*r%5E2%29%20from%200%20to%202)

[k = -1, $\alpha$ = 1, L = 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph%20of%20-Exp%5B-r%5D%2Fr%20%2B%201%2F%282*r%5E2%29%20from%200%20to%202)

What's different about these two effective potentials?  We only changed $L$ between the two graphs;  what does that imply about the allowed values of $L$ if we want a circular orbit?  (If you can't answer this question immediately, try plotting the effective potential for a few more values of $L$.  If you have access to Mathematica and know how to use it, the `Manipulate` function is your friend.)

Comment: I think I get it. The value of L should be $r_0$. Meaning that L = d(Uef)/dr at $r_0$

Comment: Not quite.  It's more that for certain values of $L$, no $r_0$ will exist.  This is different than the usual Newtonian potential, for which the effective potential has a minimum for every value of $L$.

Comment: Okay, so, how should I get the angular momentum with the potential energy? I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Given the above information, you should be able to find a relationship between $L$ and $r_0$.  Remember, the question you're being asked is "for a given $r_0$, what should $L$ be to have a circular orbit at that radius?"  (At least, I think that's what the question is asking.  It's no model of clarity.)

Comment: Hmm I don't think you're getting it right. In theory, $$L=(-mkr_0(1+\alpha r_0)e^{-\alpha r_0})^{1/2}$$

Comment: I agree with that result;  that is the value of $L$ required to have a circular orbit at radius $r_0$.  (Assuming you have $L^2$ in your centripetal potential term, rather than $L$ as you do above.)  This can be shown by setting $U'_\text{eff}(r_0) = 0$ and solving for $L$.